# Are there magical-animal zoos in the wizarding world in Harry Potter?

Tags: harry-potter, magical-creatures

The question [Did Voldemort seek out Phoenix tears?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/14791/1234) got me to wondering if there are magical-animal zoos (in England or Europe) where wizards can view creatures they might not otherwise have access to (like dragons, phoenixes, unicorns, etc). If so, they might have provided a more convenient method of access to a phoenix for Voldemort than Fawkes or [Sparky](http://harrypotter.wikia.com/wiki/Sparky).

Comment: They call it "The Forbidden Forest."

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I don't think it's a stretch to assume there certainly could be magical zoos. While it doesn't explicitly say so, there are reserves for different magical creatures.

> Perhaps the most important step in the concealment of magical creatures is the creation of safe habitats. Muggle-Repelling Charms prevent trespassers into the forests where centaurs and unicorns live, and on the lakes and rivers set aside for the use of merpeople.
>   In extreme cases, such as that of the Quintaped, whole areas have been made unplottable. Some of these safe areas must be kept under constant wizarding supervision; for example, dragon reservations.
>   *Fantastic Beasts and Where To Find Them* - pages 9-10 - Scholastic

Comment: Bermuda Triangle, what? ;P

Answer (score 1):

While their might be magic zoos, I can't see phoenixes in them. Not only would keeping them in a cage seem difficult considering their magical powers, it wouldn't be a very dignified way to keep them. Not that humans ever care, though.